# How to change the value of Stuck Thread Max Time in WebLogic server without console

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracle-fusion-middleware

I want to change the value of `Stuck Thread Max Time` property without using the console. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a WLST script to update your server configuration :

```
connect('<USERNAME>','<PASSWORD>','<HOST>:<PORT>')
edit()
startEdit()
cd('/Servers/<SERVER NAME>')
cmo.setStuckThreadMaxTime(300)
save()
activate()
```